# cloud functions truncating logs

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, firebase-console

I currently rely on getting some information from cloud functions through `console.log(information)` 
However, whenever the logs are long they are truncated when viewing on the browser. Scrolling bring up the next set of logs, hence the logs are incomplete (see attached image)
I'm aware that I can store his data in the database, but sometimes it's convenient viewing the logs as well
Anyone with a better way of going round this?
[image]

Comment: Curious about your deleted answer.  Did you find that the log presentation at Google Cloud console was not any better?

Comment: Yes, 
I viewed one log and thought my problem was solved only to find that that specific one was short

Comment: I've also tried logging on the terminal as described 
https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/writing-and-viewing-logs#viewing_logs
Still trancating

Answer (score 2):

There is no easy workaround for this.  You would have to build a string of whatever you want to log, split it into segments that fit on screen, then log those substrings separately.  Or, you could write the log somewhere else temporarily, such a database.

This is a known issue, but please feel free to [file a bug report](https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/bugs-features/) to add your voice.